# One PHP script should have one mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am making my android mobile game's server, db using php, mysql.

When user first run my game, I want to compare his `ID` with my game DB and check he is `new user` or `not`.

If he is `not new user`, I want to fetch item info he got from `db` and send it to unity client and apply.

So I am making PHP script to do this, but question is,

Here I need to do 2 times of `$sql` and `mysql_query`. First for compare `ID`, second for fetch `item info`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$userId'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
echo 'Registration Complete';
```

then, can I input these 2 process to one PHP script? In this case, how can I fetch from unity? echo is one result, isn't it?

or should I divide to 2 PHP scripts?

Comment: It should have none. And besides, there's only one query. Either it returns a result, or it does not.

Comment: Unity and Unity3D are different things, please use the correct tag next time

Comment: You are basically doing everything wrong, sorry! If you want to develop android games, then read into the basics of mobile development, this has absolutly nothing to do with PHP. If you want to write PHP, then read into the basics of PHP first, your 3 lines of code are full of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use mysql_query. Use at least [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) but (to my opinion) better use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

To answer your question: You can make two SQL statements in the same PHP file. In fact it is very common. Your code would look something like this:

```
$sql    = "select * from user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (isset($result[0])) {
    $sql    = "select * from items where user_id = ?";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // Parse result to unite all items in a readable format
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo 'registration succesful';
}
```

This is just example code and won't work but it should push you in the right direction.

EDIT:
To return multiple different kinds of data to the frontend (Unity3D) it is advised to bundle all data. Also formatting your output in a known format, e.g., JSON, would make it easier to parse the data at the frontend.

Consider the following code:

```
$response = array();
// Code to retrieve user in $user using msqli
if ($user) {
    // Retrieve items from user using mysqli
    $response['items']   = $items;
    $response['user']    = $user;
    $response['message'] = 'User authenticated';
} else {
    // Insert user into DB and save in $user using mysqli
    $response['user']    = $user;
    $response['message'] = 'User registered';
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thx for reply, so like mysqli_query($sql); ?  and how to do 2nd query? just do another mysqli_query($sql2) and  make 2 result strings to one string value?

Comment: Can I do multiple echo syntax? echo $result;  echo $result2;  and if this is possible, how can I fetch from unity?

Comment: It might be a smart idea to collect all data you want to return and make a single echo statement at the end.

Comment: I've added an example in my answer.